# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Script timed out before returning headers: application.py

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have an existing Elastic Beanstalk flask app on AWS that occasionally will not initialize and gives the following error:

```
[Mon Jan 23 10:06:51.550205 2017] [core:error] [pid 7331] [client  127.0.0.1:43790] script timed out before returning headers: application.py
[Mon Jan 23 10:10:43.910014 2017] [core:error] [pid 7329] [client 127.0.0.1:43782] End of script output before headers: application.py
```

Any ideas why this might be? Most recently I changed the project's `requirements.txt` to include `pandas==0.19.2`. Prior to that change, the program would work for several days before returning the same error. More logs/program details:

```
[Mon Jan 23 10:05:36.877664 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 7323] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Jan 23 10:05:36.886151 2017] [so:warn] [pid 7323] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ip-10-55-254-33
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Jan 23 10:05:36.887302 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7323] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Jan 23 10:05:36.887797 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 7323] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Jan 23 10:05:36.887828 2017] [:warn] [pid 7323] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.10.
[Mon Jan 23 10:05:36.887832 2017] [:warn] [pid 7323] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Mon Jan 23 10:05:36.889729 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7323] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 23 10:05:36.889744 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7323] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Jan 23 10:06:43.542607 2017] [core:error] [pid 7328] [client 127.0.0.1:43786] Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
[Mon Jan 23 10:06:47.548360 2017] [core:error] [pid 7330] [client 127.0.0.1:43788] Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
[Mon Jan 23 10:06:51.550205 2017] [core:error] [pid 7331] [client 127.0.0.1:43790] Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
[Mon Jan 23 10:10:43.910014 2017] [core:error] [pid 7329] [client 127.0.0.1:43782] End of script output before headers: application.py
```

application.py

```
import flask
from flask import request, Response
import logging
import json
import JobType1
import JobType2
import sys


application = flask.Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object('default_config')
application.debug = application.config['FLASK_DEBUG'] in ['true', 'True']`

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@application.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
  logger.info("The message received was '/', no action taken")
  response = Response("Success", status=200)
  return response


@application.route('/StartJob', methods=['POST'])
def StartJob():
  logger.info("!!start_job message received! This is the start job logger")
  print("!!start_job message received! This is the start job printer")
  response = None

if request.json is None:
    response = Response("Error, no job specified.", status=400)
else:
    message = dict()

    try:
        if request.json.has_key('TopicArn') and request.json.has_key('Message'):
            message = json.loads(request.json['Message'])
            job = message['job']
        else:
            message = request.json
            job = message['job']
        date_key = None
        try:
            date_key = message['runkey']
        except Exception as e:
            print "printing Exception:"
            print e
            pass
        start_job(job, date_key)
        response = Response("Called Job", status=200)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.exception("There was an error processing this message: %s" % request.json)
        response = Response("Error processing message", status=400)
return response


@application.route('/CronMessage', methods=['POST'])
def cron_message():
  logger.info("!!Cron message received! This is the Cron Start Logger")
  response = None
  logger.info("About to print headers of CRON***")
  job = request.headers.get('X-Aws-Sqsd-Taskname')
  start_job(job, None)
  response = Response("Called Job", status=200)
  return response


def start_job(job_name, date_key):
  logger.info("JOB NAME SUBMITTED IS:")
  logger.info(job_name)
  if job_name == 'JobType1':
      start_job_if_not_running(job_name, JobType1.main, True, date_key)
  if job_name == 'JobType2':
    start_job_if_not_running(job_name, JobType2.main, True, date_key)
  else:
    print "Submitted job nome is invalid, no job started. The invalid submitted job name was %s" % job_name


def start_job_if_not_running(job_name, program_to_execute, uses_date_key_flag, date_key):
  global running_jobs
  logger.info("running_jobs are:")
  logger.info(running_jobs)

  if job_name in running_jobs:
    logger.info("Currently running job " + job_name + ", will not start again.")
    return False
else:
    try:
        running_jobs.append(job_name)
        if uses_date_key_flag:
            logger.info("")
            program_to_execute(date_key)
        else:
            program_to_execute()
    except Exception as e:
        handle_job_end(job_name)
        print "Error in " + job_name
        error_message = str(e) + "-" + str(sys.exc_info()[0])
        print error_message
        EmailUsers.main(subject="Error in " + job_name,
                        message=error_message,
                        message_type='error',
                        date_key=date_key,
                        job_name=job_name,
                        process_name='application.py',
                        notification_group='bp_only')
    handle_job_end(job_name)


def handle_job_end(job_name):
  while job_name in running_jobs:
    running_jobs.remove(job_name)

logger.info("Process Complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  application.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

Any help is appreciated, I can share more code from the other files as necessary.

In addition, if I navigate to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf`, I see:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/application.py


<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
</VirtualHost>

LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Comment: What is the mod_wsgi configuration from Apache? When using ``numpy``, ``pandas`` etc, you must force the use of the main Python interpreter context else you can see that problem. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I've added the contents of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf` to the original question. Is this helpful? Sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: As per link, you need to add ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}%``.

Comment: @user2752159 did this fix your issue? I am experiencing the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton This worked! What I had to do was:

Edit the wsgi.conf file by connecting to the Elastic Beanstalk instance over SSH, and using `sudo -e /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf` to edit the file to add `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` anywhere in the file. (Note I didn't use the closing `%` sign like the comment above, but rather the syntax listed in the link above.

Then I had to restart the Application Server via the Elastic Beanstalk console. After this the application would load, and not give the error message! Thanks again to @GrahamDumpleton for all your help!

Comment: @user3939059 See the comment above. I'll also turn this into a formal answer now.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thank you. I wonder if the solution still works. I included the same file in my worker project but I still get the timeout error.

Comment: One of the symptoms may be an HTTP status 504 "Gateway Timeout".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The @user2752159's answer highlights the issue however I am going to add this to show how to overcome this issue in the context of AWS Beanstalk (ie. if a new instance or you deploy more code then the problem will remain fixed, rather than having to ssh into the box each time to modify `wsgi.conf`).

Create the file. (note it ends with *.config and not conf)

```
nano .ebextensions/<some_name>.config
```

add the following to `some_name.config` ([mod_wsgi docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIApplicationGroup.html))

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

add to git

```
git add .ebextensions/<some_name>.config
git commit -m 'message here'
```

deploy to beanstalk

```
eb deploy
```

Now each time you deploy, `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` will be added to `wsgi_custom.conf`, fixing the issue.

Comment: Finding this question/answer took me a while, but solved my issue - many thanks!

Comment: @DavidViktora How does WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} work actually?
I have read the doc but still don't quite get it.
Any WSGI applications in the global application group will always be executed within the context of the first interpreter created by Python when it is initialised, of the process handling the request. https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIApplicationGroup.html

Comment: I added this to my project but still get the script time out error.

Comment: remember to pay attention to the names when doing it:
.ebextensions/<some_name>.CONFIG

i was stuck with this for hours...

Comment: This resolved my issue but not sure what was the issue. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This was exactly my issue. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Resolved my problem with EBS Python 3.6 with a Flask Server. Thanks.

Comment: This was absolutely the fix I needed.  I just don't know why it works.  But, at least the site loads!

Answer (score 11):

Many thanks to @GrahamDumpleton for his help. The solution I used was:

-Edit the wsgi.conf file found at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf` on the Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance.

To do this I used the command `sudo -e /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf` to open the editor, hit INSERT to start editing, and added `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` anywhere in the file. I then his ESCAPE and used the command `:wq` to save the changes.

After this I selected Restart App Servers from the Action drop-down of the Elastic Beanstalk console. After this, the program would load and give the 
`AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'` message, but not the error messages afterwards. In addition, the application would receive SQS messages and run as expected.

One thing to note, is that it appears the wsgi.conf file will revert if any configuration changes are made to the Elastic Beanstalk configuration. I'm not sure of a way around this, but if I find something I'll post it here.

Thanks again to @GrahamDumpleton for his prompt response and help in solving this issue!