# On AWS Elastic Beanstalk how to fix the "Script timed out before returning headers: application.py" error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, timeout

I am new to using AWS, and have run into what appears to be a fairly common problem. I have created a deep learning app in Python which runs fine on Flask locally. However, when I create the app using AWS Elastic Beanstalk it builds fine. I am also able to run a simpler version of it on Heroku, but need to run the final app on AWS due to required resources.

However, when run the site fails to load and I get the following error page:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Checking the AWS error logs shows that the last few logs are:

> [Fri Jan 03 20:05:13.255635 2020] [:error] [pid ~]
>   /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>
> [Fri Jan 03 20:05:13.255641 2020] [:error] [pid ~]   _np_qint32 =
>   np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
>
> [Fri Jan 03 20:05:13.255672 2020] [:error] [pid ~]
>   /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>
> [Fri Jan 03 20:05:13.255677 2020] [:error] [pid ~]   np_resource =
>   np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
>
> [Fri Jan 03 20:06:15.487582 2020] [core:error] [pid ~] [client ~]
>   Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
>
> [Fri Jan 03 20:06:19.485185 2020] [core:error] [pid ~] [client ~]
>   Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
>
> [Fri Jan 03 20:06:23.489571 2020] [core:error] [pid ~] [client ~]
>   Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
>
> [Fri Jan 03 20:09:54.675100 2020] [core:error] [pid ~] [client ~]
>   Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
>
> [Fri Jan 03 20:10:18.094053 2020] [core:error] [pid ~] [client ~] End
>   of script output before headers: application.py
>
> [Fri Jan 03 20:10:18.094299 2020] [core:error] [pid ~] [client ~] End
>   of script output before headers: application.py

From reading around I first thought that I have may have run into the same problem discussed here:
[AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Script timed out before returning headers: application.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812497/aws-elastic-beanstalk-script-timed-out-before-returning-headers-application-p)

However, when I make the suggested addition to the wsgi.conf file I still find the same problem, even after rebuilding the environment. I'm not sure if I have made a mistake in implementation or if my problem is fundamentally different. If someone is able to shed some light on what may be the problem I would really appreciate it. I want to fix this issue and learn more about running code on these types of remote servers.

Please let me know if there are any details I have not provided which would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer?

Comment: No, I still do not know how to fix this. If anyone has any thoughts please let me know. I'd really like to get my app back up and running.