# Django APP on AWS Beanstalk stopping during process

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have developed a Django APP in AWS Beanstalk. it works but after the lastest deploy,
the process starts correctly but at a certain position in the code, it stops without errors (I have seen in both AWS Beanstalk logs and my app logs) and doesn't go ahead.

is it possible that I should erase or cancel some cache file or something like that?

In addition, the AWS logs immediately after the last execution return:

```
Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py on elastic beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477268/script-timed-out-before-returning-headers-wsgi-py-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: @dirkgroten. I'm reading similar problem. In the previous questions there is an answer that said of adding
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}, but where I should include it?